# Disable analytics but still use crashlytics with iOS SDK

Tags: ios, analytics, crashlytics

I want to use Crashlytics for crashes only and disable any analytics events for my iOS app. I disabled everything I could find in setting:

[image: App settings]

but I still see that the app is hitting `https://e.crashlytics.com/spi/v2/events` endpoint regularly and posting some data.

I am wondering if there is a way to disable sending any events apart from crashes. In addition to it will it have more granular settings after migration to Firebase?

Thanks.

Comment: Following this documentation (docs.fabric.io/apple/answers/…) should stop you from receiving any analytics data on your Dashboard. Based on that screenshot it seems you've already disabled analytics, so I'm surprised any events are still being sent. Could you specify which events you are seeing metrics for on your Dashboard?

Comment: @OlegKodysh that's the thing I am trying to figure out. The link on docs you sent mentions that there is a way to disable analytics. Last time I looked at this with Crashlytics (about two months ago) I managed to disable the analytics and my proxy showed no events are being sent. However after taking the latest version of Crashlytics and a migration to Firebase I see events are sent and there is no option to disable it either on Crashlytics or Firebase dashboard. I also don't see any events on the dashboard(s). Crashes are coming through though.

Comment: Ah, I see. It seems like you're referring to Google Analytics which is the Fabric Analytics equivalent in Firebase, however it uses a completely different SDK. If you want to remove Google Analytics events from your Firebase Dashboard, you just need to remove the Google Analytics dependency from your app. Crashlytics will still work without Google Analytics, however please note you will not receive Crash Free User metrics without the Google Analytics SDK.

More information here https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/get-started?platform=ios